One file ocaml program with a signature, a module and a main function
I am still unable to install OCaml correctly on my Windows computer. That's why I use the online compiler from here and must program everything in one file!
I want to have a module with a signature and a main method. The following program
module Atom : sig 
 val square: x:int -> int
end

module Atom = struct
 let square x = x * x
end

let () =
  print_int (Atom.square 5)

doesn't compile and the Error message is:
Output:
File "./HelloWorld.ml", line 5, characters 0-6:
5 | module Atom = struct
    ^^^^^^
Error: Syntax error

If I remove the first part with the signature, everything works. How to add the signature correctly?

I found the error. The syntax for the signature was simply wrong. This worked:
module type Atom = sig 
 val square: int -> int
end

module Atom : Atom = struct
 let square x = x * x
end

let () =
  print_int (Atom.square 5)


When it comes to installing OCaml on Windows, I suggest if you have not yet tried it to install WSL2, then install opam through that and using opam, install OCaml.
As for your code, while you have solved the syntax error, please be aware that the explicit signature is only strictly needed if you are not making everything in your module visible to the outside world. You could just as easily have written:
module Atom = struct
 let square x = x * x
end

let () =
  print_int (Atom.square 5)

